# Android .aab application in google play store(React native app distribution)

Tags: android, react-native, software-distribution

Our Application basically has embedded web assets into the react native layer.

Now we did few enhancements and try to publish the application. APK and IPA was Tested internally and client, which is working good. Uploaded  .aab file in the play store, which also approved.

After publishing, we try to test in android(iOS working good). We are facing the white screen issue after the splash screen. Because of this issue we uploaded the APK and which working without any intervention in play store.

We tried to resolve this whitescreen issue with the below solutions, but no luck.

1. Set true and false to enableHermes flag.
   https://blog.echobind.com/optimizing-your-android-build-for-react-native-e1e403e9059
2. Included the soloader
   https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26400#issuecomment-539395814
3. Updated the react native version- app force closed

Comment: Did you find any solution to this AAB problem or you continued with APK releases?

Comment: Set True to the enableHermes, which will worked.